# Can't resume from hibernation - glitched screen

Tags: nvidia, hibernate, mbr

I have Ubuntu installed on a USB drive.
I don't use UEFI since I wanted to use this USB drive on other PCs.

When I try *sudo systemctl hibernate*, my laptop hibernates. When I try to resume from hibernation, I get this glitched screen:

[image]

I tried to shut down my laptop and when I tried to boot Ubuntu again, it has booted without any problems, but any of my opened programs didn't resume.

I tried to use *sudo hibernate*, but I got this error:

`hibernate:Warning: Tuxonice binary signature file not found. Some modules failed to unload: nvidia_drm nvidia_modeset nvidia hibernate: Aborting suspend due to errors in ModulesUnloadBlacklist (use --force to override).`

I tried it with *--force*, and I still see the same glitched screen...

Then, when I tried to reboot my laptop, it resumed sucessfuly, but without WiFi.

NOTE: I already tried to set the resume device in */etc/default/grub*, but still without any luck. I had the same problem in Ubuntu 19.10. I have a swap space on my encrypted LVM, but I had the same issue with unencrypted LVM. I'll try it in UEFI and see if it helps...

```
Ubuntu version: 20.04 LTS
Boot method: Legacy (MBR)
Model: HP Probook 470 G4
CPU: Intel Core i7 7th Gen.
GPU1: Intel HD Graphics 620
GPU2: NVIDIA GeForce 930MX
```

EDIT: I tried to boot my USB drive on another HP laptop and I was able to resume from hibernation. I also tried to hibernate on the second laptop and then resume on my main laptop and it worked too! I think there's something wrong with my laptop. It seems the problem is not in resuming, but in hibernating

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the Nvidia card, you could try switching to the proprietary Nvidia driver.  I had very similar issues with 20.04 installed on my hard drive. I saw the same type of noisy glitched screen when trying to wake from suspend. After I switched from the opensource X.org Nouveau driver to the Nvidia driver the problem went away.

To switch the driver I opened the "Additional Drivers" application, which came up as the Additional Drivers tab of the "Software and Updates" application. There I saw this option. It took several minutes for the application to load and install the driver.  The effective change took place after rebooting.

Comment: Thank you, I think the problem's gone now. Hibernation works both for Intel and NVIDIA GPU.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to hibernate with Intel GPU without any problems.
It worked much better on UEFI than on legacy.
I'll use the Intel GPU instead of NVIDIA before I hibernate again...